# Power Automate - AD Module - Password Couldn't be set

Tags: active-directory, power-automate-desktop

Just trying to make basic flow that creates a user in Active Directory, managed to get connected to the server, however I am getting this error when using the "Create User" action.

```
Correlation Id: 6928e489-caaa-41e6-a04e-881d1fde8536

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.: Microsoft.PowerPlatform.PowerAutomate.Desktop.Actions.SDK.ActionException: Password couldn't be set. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: One or more input parameters are invalid

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.ActiveDirectory.Actions.Types.UserEntry.SetPassword(String password)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.ActiveDirectory.Actions.ActiveDirectoryBase.HandleException(Exception ex)
at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.ActiveDirectory.Actions.CreateUserAction.Execute(ActionContext context)
at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.ActionRunner.Run(IActionStatement statement, Dictionary`2 inputArguments, Dictionary`2 outputArguments)
```

The password I am trying to set is certainly of the correct length and complexity, and doesn't break any of our rules.

I am also using the desktop version, is that better or worse? Should I use the online version?

Thank you.

Comment: "The password I am trying to set is certainly of the correct length and complexity, and doesn't break any of our rules." - are you 100% sure the password doesn't contain any parts of the user's _name_? If a user is named `Jon Doe`, then neither `jon` nor `doe` can be part of the password

Comment: It certainly doesn't no, That was my first thought, Firstname/Surname are competely unique from the password.